# Upgrading to a specific version of android

Tags: updates

I am looking to upgrade (not downgrade) my tablet to a specific version of android.

Is there a way to do this?  Every search I do comes up with downgrading!

Is there a site that hosts legacy versions of android updates? And is it possible to upgrade to one of these?

Thanks!

Comment: You ask about "site that hosts legacy versions" - older versions than what you have are always called "downgrade".

Comment: Please mention your device name... There are many websites that host stock firmware of different brand devices..

Comment: @andy yan ever try critical thinking?  its not hard to figure out what i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates are *device / carrier* specific - there isn't an update that works on every device or any device, si there's no question of an universal repository

If there is an update available for your device, it can be activated by clicking the *System updates* in the *about phone /device* portion of settings (usually, but you may find it elsewhere in your settings

If it says there is no update, then **you can't** (though in some cases OEM hosts on *their* site an update to be manually downloaded and applied, but it's more of an exception)

If you want to upgrade at any cost, you will have to root your device and flash a custom ROM